# SQL Server : check if table exists

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to check if a table accessed through openquery exists with the following code but it does not work:

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SADATABASE, ' select     *
                           from xx_201509_T                           ' 
            ) )
```

Comment: You'll get better answers here if instead of "does not work" you describe what you expect to happen, and what's happening instead. What RDBMS (database system) is the database you're accessing through OpenQuery running?

Comment: I need to check if the table exists. Accessing a sybase database through openquery

Comment: So, basically you need to find out how to check if a table exists in Sybase, and then pass that query to OpenQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[xx_201509_T]') AND type in (N'U'))
***DO WHATEVER HERE***
```

Comment: you need to add a statement after

Comment: Like what? All i want to do is check if the table exists then select

Comment: Like select * from xx_201509_T

Comment: {IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[xx_201509_T]') AND type in (N'U'))
select 
*
FROM OPENQUERY(server1, 'select 
*
         from object_id([dbo].[xx_201509_T]
         where co_cde = 15   
         and cust_no in (1780066
          ) ' 
   ) 
}

Comment: select * from object_id looks strange

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID('xx_201509_T', 'U')
```

if it's `NULL`, then the table does not exist

EDIT: so in your openquery use it like this:

```
IF (SELECT objectID FROM OPENQUERY(SADATABASE, 'SELECT OBJECT_ID(''xx_201509_T'', ''U'') as objectID') )  IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
 print 'xx_201509_T TABLE EXISTS'
END
```

Comment: I get the error: Wrong number of parameters to function 'object_id'

Comment: @krtek Do we even know which version of Sybase the query is being executed on?